# Commons-net: How to send a file over FTP using ASCII without changing LF to CRLF

Tags: java, ftp, ascii, newline, apache-commons-net

I need to send a file over FTP (I'm using commons-net Java library) using ASCII mode (can't use Binary mode because the host uses a different way of storing data), but I need the LF characters to stay as LF and not to be transformed to CRLF.

Indeed I need LF to stay as LF and CRLF to stay as CRLF. 
So far I couldn't find a way of doing this.

If there is no way of doing this with commons-net but someone knows how to do it with a different library would be appreciated

Thank you all for your responses.
See you

**Solution**
Finally I had to change to the ftp4j library, which works as I wanted out of the box.

Comment: What **exact** "different way of storing data" are your trying to overcome?  Typical differences, such an endianess, would either not be an issue, or not be corrected, by this choice.  Some other character scheme (EBCDIC?) would, but you'd probably need to come up with an appropriate translation table (far beyond the CR/LF issue) and not simply use "ASCII mode"

Comment: The HOST is a Z/OS, i'm not sure what those difference are, I've been told that I couldn't use BINARY mode, I tryed, but the file where corrupted.

Comment: Corrupted how?  Somebody is either giving you bad information or not holding up their end of the spec.  What type of data?

Comment: IF I send a text file using BINARY from Windows to Z/OS the file ends up corrupted as a bunch of Hex codes without any meaning.

Comment: Actually you were right, the file it's not corrupted, it's just that I'm sending a ISO-8859-1 file and the Z/OS only understands EBCDIC.

Comment: Really?  While of legacy origins, that's a system with enough modern capabilities I'm sure it has a way to handle ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

The point of ASCII mode is exactly to have the line ending specific for the platform. So on UNIX system it will be LF and on windows CRLF. There is no way around it inside the client, because the server might convert the data. If you pass the data unmodified there is no way around using binary.

Comment: I doubt that it works with all servers, because the server is free to convert data transferred with ASCII into their native representation (e.g. platform specific line endings). There is no way for the client to control this, as long it is using ASCII.

Comment: Beware that ftp on Linux systems seems to have suddenly started enforcing CRLF and spitting out the "bare linefeeds received" error.  wget, curl, filezilla work, cli ftp does not.